# Docusign visibility settings in Branding resource file

Tags: docusignapi

1) In the Signing header, there is a "More" options list.

Is there a way to remove the "View Certficate" option? According to the branding guide, the text can be changed but there's no option to set the visibility of options.

2) In the Document Download dialog box, is there a way to remove the "Archive of all documents" option. Again, there is a way to set the text but not the visibility in the resource file.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question -- I believe it is possible to remove the "View Certificate" option (to prevent recipients from being able to access/view the Certificate of Completion). However, this is done via an account setting that you don't have access to -- you'll need to contact either your Account Rep (if you're working with one) or DocuSign Support to request that this option be set for your account.

Regarding the second question -- I don't think I recall hearing about a setting that would specifically disallow only the "Archive of all documents" option -- but you should confirm with your Account Rep or Support when you speak with them.  On a related note -- perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but it is possible to prevent recipients from Downloading documents at all via these two settings in the Signing Resource File:

```
<data name="DocuSign_SigningAllowDownload">false</data>
<data name="DocuSignComplete_AllowDownload">false</data>
```